# Spring Boot & Angular 2: downloading a file from server

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot, download

I have app with Angular frontend and Spring Boot backend. In frontend I have html button, via I want to download file. Proble is that it behaves differently on remote server and on localhost:

1. **localhost** - after pressing button **file is downloaded**

   ```
   <button download="output.txt" href="http://localhost:8080/output/output.txt"> Download </button>
   ```
2. **remote server**: after pressing button **nothing happens**

   ```
   <button download="output.txt" href="https://www.bla.com/output/output.txt"> Download </button>
   ```

However, if I copy the url **https://www.bla.com/output/output.txt** into a browser the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to used:

```
<a download="output.txt" href="https://www.bla.com/output/output.txt">Download</a>
```